# Mongoose Different Model.Discriminator() Schemas create duplicate key errors

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, discriminator

I get a duplicate key error, when trying to create an Instance of the Discriminator `Admin` of the BaseSchema `User`.

The error is regarding a field named `customerId` which is set as `unique: true` on **another** Discriminator named `Customer`, also of the BaseSchema `User`.

But that field is neither part of `User` nor `Admin`. Only part of `Customer`

#### UserSchema

```
const UserSchema = new Schema({
    email: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
    firstname: { type: String, required: true },
    lastname: { type: String, required: true },
    role: { type: String, required: true },     
    apikey: { type: String }
})
```

### CustomerSchema

```
const CustomerSchema = new Schema({
    customerId: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
    mobile: { type: String, unique: true },    
    birthdate: { type: Date, required: true },
    password: { type: String }, 
    role: { type: String, default: 'customer' },        
    phone: { type: String },
    isActive: { type: Boolean, default: false },        
    events: [ { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Events' } ]
})
```

### AdminSchema

```
const AdminSchema = new Schema({
    email: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },

    firstname: { type: String, required: true },
    lastname: { type: String, required: true },
    password: { type: String }, 
    role: { type: String, required: true, default: 'admin' },

    apikey: { type: String },
})
```

When i try to create more than **one** Instance of this Schema, I get the following error:

`E11000 duplicate key error collection: database.users index: customerId_1 dup key: { : null }`

So apparently MongoDB sets all the properties of every Discriminator adding fields to the users Collection as "null", even when they are not part of the Discriminator that's being instanciated.

The Problem is, that I can't just come up with fake `customerIds`, since they come from an external source and are being referenced outside of my application.

Thanks in advance.

Best regards
- Ben

Comment: check out https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/6347 and https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/6343 for an explanation and a couple of solutions. TL;DR you need to create either a `sparse` or `partial unique index` instead of just a `unique index`

Comment: I overflew both issues, and they should help me with my problem. Much appreciated :)